# Datatable tr click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to do some operations after clicking a particular row. I followed the API and this is what I ended up with but the click event is not working.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#employees').dataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "show_employee_processor.php",

        "aoColumns": [
        { "sTitle": "Empoyee ID" },
        { "sTitle": "Last Name" },
        { "sTitle": "First Name" }, 
        { "sTitle": "BBan Number" },
        ]
    } );

    table.$('tr').click(function() {
        var data = table.fnGetData( this );
        alert(data);
    });


} );
```

The datatable is getting drawn but the click event is not working. What am I missing?

Comment: You are not missing anything. The code is perfectly correct, and similar to doc examples. You can see your code in action here -> http://jsfiddle.net/7LmMg/ - I bet you get some errors in the console. Do you have the event-assignment outside the ready-block? Is table decalared elsewhere as `var table;`??

Comment: No error in the console and no deceleration outside the ready block. The jsfiddle is working. Also I don't have var table; declared anywhere. I have changed the variable name but its still the same.

Comment: What version of datatables are you using?

Comment: latest version v1.9.4

Comment: it works well on 1.9.4 also -> http://jsfiddle.net/38gjP/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try delegated event:

```
table.on('click','tr',function() {
        var data = table.fnGetData( this );
        alert(data);
    });
```

or:

```
$('#employees').on('click','tr',function() {
            var data = table.fnGetData( this );
            alert(data);
        });
```

Comment: @EhsanSAjjad, This is working but I can't see why mine is not working.

Comment: what issue coming can you tell?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#employees tr").click( function( e ) {
          if ( $(this).hasClass('row_selected')==false ) {
                table .$('tr.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected');
                $(this).addClass('row_selected');
                    var data = table.fnGetData( this );
                    alert(data);
          }
      else{
           $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
           }
    });
```

CSS>

```
#employees tr.row_selected{
    background-color:#B5CCD2;
    opacity:0.95;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```